# How to calculate standard deviation for 7 day intervals

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter

This is my dataframe, how could I calculate the `(standard deviation) * 7`for the first seven days, then the next 7 days then the 7 days after that, to get the weekly volatility from the column `log returns`. And put it into a dataframe, I tried a few functions that I wrote but they dont work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a rolling window with a time-aware offset (7 days is represented by `"7D"`) using [`pandas.DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html#pandas-dataframe-rolling):

```
>>> df["log"].rolling("7D").std()
```

This will look at your datetime index, take current take the last 7 days (including current date/index) and calculate the standard variation of the "log" column by using [`pandas.DataFrame.std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html#pandas-dataframe-std).